# mapping a domain to a directory in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have two domains. I'm using `www.example.com` for my normal site and `examp.le` for the URL shortener.

I have perfect setup for www.example.com with all rewrite rules.

In my web root for www.example.com, there's a directory called `examp.le`.

I wish to redirect all the traffic hitting `examp.le` to the index.php in `/absolute/path/www.example.com/examp.le`

So my question has basically two sub-questions:

1. How do I modify the default.conf file so that examp.le maps to the directory in my web root?
2. How do I pass `SOMEURLIDENTIFIER` in `http://examp.le/SOMEURLIDENTIFIER` to `http://examp.le/index.php?i=SOMEURLIDENTIFIER` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create new `server` instance in nginx config for hostname *examp.le*. It should look something like this:

```
server {
  ....
  listen 80;
  server_name examp.le;
  root /absolute/path/www.example.com/examp.le;    # This is your 1

  ....

  location / {
    ....
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?=$1 last;         # This is your 2
      break;
    }
    ....
  }

  ....

  location ~ \.php$ {                              # PHP processing
    ....
  }

}
```

Comment: Eugh, replace the `if` with a `try_files`, please.

Comment: Yes, like @womble advised, the, `if` section could be replaced with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args`.